# Viewing the number of blocks for a file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How can I view how many blocks has a file been broken into, in a Hadoop file system?

Answer (score 45):

We can use hadoop file system check command to know the blocks for the specific file.

Below is the command:

```
hadoop fsck [path] [options]
```

To view the blocks for the specific file :

```
hadoop fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks
```

Answer (score 4):

**hadoop fsck  filetopath**

used the above commad in CDH 5. Got the below Error.

hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: line 262: exec: : not found

Use the below command and it worked good

**hdfs fsck filetopath**

Answer (score 3):

It is always a good idea to use hdfs instead of hadoop as 'hadoop' version is deprecated.

Here is the command with hdfs and to find the details on a file named 'test.txt' in the root, you would write

`hdfs fsck /test.txt -files -blocks -locations`

Answer (score -4):

This should work..

```
hadoop fs -stat "%o" /path/to/file
```

Comment: `%o` is the block size, not the number of blocks, per http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#stat