# Hadoop and Mapreduce configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have few questions regarding Hadoop architecture

1. In Mapreduce can we dynamically modify the block size and no of mappers,if so how do we do?
2. Hows does the block gets created in HDFS. For example the hadoop framework is installed on say redhat linux machine.  The default block size of linux filesystem is 4k. Is the HDFS block a logical wrapper on the 4k blocks or how does a block gets created. also is it parallel or sequential? because for example a file has only 32 MB since the block size is 64 MB. Is the remaining 32 Mb reusable?
3. I want to see the location(data node) of all the  blocks of particular file I just copied to the HDFS. Is there any command to do that from a single location?
4. If I move the video file to HDFS, how does the block allocation happen for this video file

Comment: Too many questions in one question :)

Comment: Any hint on any of the above questions will be very useful for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. In Mapreduce can we dynamically modify the block size and no of mappers?

I assume that you are looking for HDFS file system.

**HDFS** is distributed storage system and **Mapreduce** is distributed processing framework.

HDFS block size can be changed with ***hdfs-site.xml***

Have a look at documentation [page](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for various HDFS configurations.

**dfs.blocksize**

**134217728**  ( default value)

The default block size for new files, in bytes. You can use the following suffix (case insensitive): ***k(kilo), m(mega), g(giga), t(tera), p(peta), e(exa)*** to specify the size (such as 128k, 512m, 1g, etc.), Or provide complete size in bytes **(such as 134217728 for 128 MB)**.

Relate SE question:

[How to set data block size in Hadoop ? Is it advantage to change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34419869/how-to-set-data-block-size-in-hadoop-is-it-advantage-to-change-it/34420591#34420591)

> 2. Hows does the block gets created in HDFS. For example the hadoop framework is installed on say redhat linux machine.  The default block size of linux filesystem is 4k. Is the HDFS block a logical wrapper on the 4k blocks or how does a block gets created. also is it parallel or sequential? because for example a file has only 32 MB since the block size is 64 MB. Is the remaining 32 Mb reusable?

Remaining 32 MB is re-usable.

Have a look at this SE question for HDFS block write operation :

[Hadoop file write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464187/hadoop-file-write/34464676#34464676)

> 3. I want to see the location(data node) of all the  blocks of particular file I just copied to the HDFS. Is there any command to do that from a single location?

```
hadoop fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks
```

Related SE question:

[Viewing the number of blocks for a file in hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168427/viewing-the-number-of-blocks-for-a-file-in-hadoop)

> 4. If I move the video file to HDFS, how does the block allocation happen for this video file?

**Number of blocks = File size in MB / DFS block size in MB**

Once number of blocks have been identified, those blocks will be written as explained in Hadoop file write question.

Few more good questions:

[Hadoop chunk size vs split vs block size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704312/hadoop-chunk-size-vs-split-vs-block-size/34704514#34704514)

[How hadoop decides how many nodes will do map and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282121/how-hadoop-decides-how-many-nodes-will-do-map-and-reduce-tasks/33287988#33287988)