# How is Spark's default partitions calculated for HadoopPartitions?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I'm reading [Jacek Laskowski's online book about Apache Spark](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-partitions.html), and regarding partitioning, he states that

> By default, a partition is created for each HDFS partition, which by
>   default is 64MB

I'm not extremely familiar with HDFS, but I ran into some questions replicating this statement. I have a file called `Reviews.csv` which is about 330MB text file of Amazon food reviews. Given the default 64MB blocks, I'd expect `ceiling(330 / 64) = 6` partitions. However, when I load the files into my Spark Shell, I get 9 partitions:

```
scala> val tokenized_logs = sc.textFile("Reviews.csv")
tokenized_logs: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> tokenized_logs
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> tokenized_logs.partitions
res1: Array[org.apache.spark.Partition] = Array(org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c1, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c2, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c3, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c4, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c5, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c6, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c7, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c8, org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@3c9)

scala> tokenized_logs.partitions.size
res2: Int = 9
```

I do notice that if I create another smaller version of `Reviews.csv` called `Reviews_Smaller.csv` that is only 135MB, I have a significantly reduced partition size:

```
scala> val raw_reviews = sc.textFile("Reviews_Smaller.csv")
raw_reviews: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = Reviews_Smaller.csv MapPartitionsRDD[11] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> raw_reviews.partitions.size
res7: Int = 4
```

However, by my math, there should be `ceiling(135 / 4) = 3` partitions, not 4.

I'm running everything locally, on my MacBook Pro. Can anyone help explain how the number of default partitions is calculated for HDFS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets):

> By default, Spark creates one partition for each block of the file
>   (blocks being 128MB by default in HDFS), but you can also ask for a
>   higher number of partitions by passing a larger value. Note that you
>   cannot have fewer partitions than blocks.

128MB is only the *default* HDFS block size but for any file can actually be something different. The number of partitions in your case means that your file is written using a non-default block size (or more likely, consists of multiple smaller files).

See [this excellent SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168427/viewing-the-number-of-blocks-for-a-file-in-hadoop) for the ways to determine the number of blocks an HDFS file is split into.

Comment: Thanks for this. What are some typical reasons why my file might be written using a non-default block size? I don't remember adjusting any configurations on HDFS.

Comment: It entirely depends on how the file was written.